# What is the use of '|' in join operation in TCL?

Tags: tcl

I have the following code snippet :

```
proc splitstr {text exprs} {
    if {$text eq {}} {
        return $text
    }
    set exprs [join $exprs |]
}
```

What does this '|' do in join operation?
What if I remove this from the operation?Is it a safety check for something?

Comment: I fail to understand why sth. that joins substrings into a string is called `splitstr`, the proc describes the inverse operation.

Answer (score 1):

The third argument of the command `join` is the *joinString*. The `join` command inserts the *joinString* in between each list element. From the [man page](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/join.htm):

> This command returns the string formed by joining all of the elements
>   of *list* together with *joinString* separating each adjacent pair of
>   elements.

```
set data {1 2 3 4 5}
join $data ", "
     → 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

Note that `|` has no special interpretation in Tcl; it is just a one character long string.

Comment: `|` has some meaning in expressions (where it means bitwise-OR, or logical-shortcutting-OR when doubled up as `||`) but the rest of Tcl just treats it as an ordinary character.

Comment: There are some more places in Tcl where `|` has special meaning: regular expressions and command pipelines come to mind.

Comment: Thanks for the response.But, since the join string need to be specified in quotes and here it not specified that way. Is this '|' serving as join string then it would have made all the elements as 1|2|3|4|5. 
Or is this '|' serving some other purpose?

Comment: @nihaldixit The join string does not need to be specified in quotes. The example uses quotes because of the whitespace otherwise being a word delimiter in Tcl syntax. The join string in your question will indeed result in `1|2|3|4|5`, without it `1 2 3 4 5`. I'm having hard time figuring out the last part of your comment. Is there a follow-up question?